# PInescript plotcandle offset? Script that changes the closing price of the candle to the open of next

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Trying to modify a no gap script where the close of the candle is replaced by the open of the next one. Found a public script, modified a little bit but can't make it to work as the candle before the last disappears from the chart. Would appreciate your help!

```
    //@version=5

indicator("No gaps", overlay=true)

myOpen = open
myClose = close
myHigh = high
myLow = low

if bar_index==last_bar_index or bar_index==last_bar_index-1
    myOpen := open
    myClose := close
    myHigh := high
    myLow := low
    
else 
    myOpen := open[1]
    myClose := open[0]
    myHigh := high[1]
    myLow := low[1]


candleColor = myOpen <= myClose ? color.teal : color.red

plotcandle(myOpen, myHigh, myLow, myClose, color=candleColor, bordercolor=candleColor, wickcolor=candleColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

`plotcandle()` has no `offset` argument. So, it cannot be done with that.

You need to plot your own candle using a `box` for the body and a `line` for the wicks.

However, there is a limit on the number of drawings you can have on your chart so you won't see the complete history with this approach.